# Regexp date extraction for Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to extract the date part from a string "
Verify renter did not pick up vehicle amt 400$.

Action Taken:Need Followup Call with Supplier

Next Action DateTime:  04-May-2023 09:00:00  Local"

I have tried to use '\d{1,2}' but for a few it extracts the 40 from 400$ and I have also tried to use substr(comment,-28) to extract "04-May-2023 09:00:00  Local" but in few cases it has only EST mentioned in the end hence this is not working in such cases.

need your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on sample data you posted:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'Verify renter did not pick up vehicle amt 400$.
  3    Action Taken:Need Followup Call with Supplier
  4    Next Action DateTime: 04-May-2023 09:00:00 Local' from dual
  5    union all
  6    select 'whatever text goes here 500$ and action taken was: nothing while
  7    next action DateTime: 01-Sep-2023 11:00:00 EST' from dual
  8    ),
```

a simple option is to use `substr + instr` combinations; I did it step-by-step to make it more clear, but you can (if you want) *merge* them into one.

Also, it **depends** on source data. As you posted only one example, we can only try to **imagine** what else you might be having. However, as there's no evidence that there actually **is** anything different, here you are.

```
  9  temp as
 10    -- extract everything after "DateTime"
 11    (select substr(col, instr(col, 'DateTime')) val
 12     from test
 13    )
 14  -- extract everything between the 1st and and the 3rd space
 15  select substr(val, instr(val, ':') + 2,
 16                     instr(val, ' ', 1, 3) - instr(val, ':') - 1
 17               ) result
 18  from temp;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
04-May-2023 09:00:00
01-Sep-2023 11:00:00

SQL>
```

Comment: I am able to get this for 04-May-2023 09:00:00 Local but not able to get for the ones for 04-May-2023 09:00:00 EST

Comment: Why not? There's no difference if text looks the same (i.e. date value follows the "DateTime:" string. I edited code which now contains value with EST at the end; have a look - you'll see that this code works for given specifications.